# Why is my new nameserver receiving queries for domains that haven't yet registered it?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, dns-hosting

I've been running `ns1.acmehosting.com` and `ns2.acmehosting.com` for several years as authoritative nameservers for several hundred domains. I've recently added `ns3.acmehosting.com`, hosted in another data center.

I've updated the domain registration for `acmehosting.com` and added `ns3` as a nameserver. I've added an `NS` record to `acmehosting.com` for `ns3`.

`ns3` has been fully configured (using `bind`) as a slave and all my zones are loaded and responding properly.

Here's the puzzling part: of the hundreds of domains I host, I've only so far updated the registration and NS records for three of them: `acmehosting.com`, `abcd.com`, and `wxyz.com`

As expected, when I run `dnstop`, I see several queries for the above three domains. But I also see occasional queries, from a variety of client IP addresses, for other domains I host, even though I haven't yet updated their domain registration with `ns3` as a third nameserver, nor have I added the third `NS` record to the zones for those domains.

Why are these domains getting queried, and how do clients even know to query `ns3` before I've updated the domain registrations or `NS` records?

Is it because `ns3.acmehosting.com` has already been fully configured? Are clients somehow assuming/extrapolating that a third nameserver exists from the other available records?

Comment: Probably just lots of network probing for testing for recursive servers, to be used in DDoS attacks.

Comment: Difficult to help you without seeing the true names involved. But no, clients are not inventing nameservers names. If they find out about `ns3` it is because it is listed somewhere (or you just observe random probes)